# How does Promise chain work when one callback doesn't return any promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> ***When a .then() lacks the appropriate function that returns a Promise object, processing simply continues to the next link of the chain.*** Therefore, a chain can safely omit every handleRejection until the final .catch(). Similarly, .catch() is really just a .then() without a slot for handleFulfilled.

Considering:

> The methods promise.then(), promise.catch(), and promise.finally() are used to associate further action with a promise that becomes settled. These methods also return a newly generated promise object, which can optionally be used for chaining;

How does Promise chain work when one callback doesn't return any promise?

Comment: The promise up the chain catches any exception and if it intercepts one it will make a "fail" out of it and if it receives any other value, it will make it a "success".

Comment: That sentence "*When a .then() lacks the appropriate function*" does not refer to the case where your callback doesn't return a promise, but to the case where you don't pass in a callback, such as `.then(onFulfilled, null)`, `.then(null, onRejected)`, or `.then(null, null)`.

Comment: @Bergi that is informative. Thank you. Write an answer please.

Comment: That "When a .then() lacks ...." paragraph isn't the best. I'm not sure I would want to be learning about Promises from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the promise chain returns a promise, it will call the next then (or catch) with the resolved (or rejected) value of that promise. If it doesn't, then it'll just call the next `then` with the returned value (or `undefined` if nothing was returned):

```js
const myPromise = myApiCall().then(response => {
   return anotherApiCallThatReturnsAPromise(response);
}).then(secondResponse => {
   // this is the resolved value of anotherApiCall...
   return secondResponse;
}).catch(err => {
 // this error could be because myApiCall failed or because anotherApiCall... failed
})
```

```js
const myPromise = myApiCall().then(response => {
   return 42
}).then(value => {
   // value is 42
}).catch(err => {
 // this error, if present, is because myApiCall failed
})
```

Extrapolating, let's return nothing from the first callback:

```js
const myPromise = myApiCall().then(response => {
   // notice we do not return anything here
   // we just call a function - i.e. return undefined
   doSomeWorkAndReturnNothing();
}).then(value => {
   // value is undefined because nothing was returned from the previous `then`
}).catch(err => {
 // this error, if present, is because myApiCall failed
})
```

Just for fun, here's what is looks like using `await` in an `async` function:

```js
const myFunc = async () => {
   try {
     const response = await myApiCall();
     const secondResponse = await anotherApiCallThatReturnsAPromise(response);
     return secondResponse;
   } catch(err) {
     // this error could be because either of the previous two await-ed calls failed
   }

}
```